# How to check if allocated memory was freed?

Tags: command-line, memory

Does anyone know which command I need to enter on the terminal, so I can check whether all allocated memory was successfully freed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux you can use `free` to see the amount of memory used. Using `free` before and after a process was executed you might be able to see if all memory is released. Keep in mind though that other applications might have allocated or released memory in the mean time. If you want to monitor a process while it is allocating and/or releasing memory try `pmap -x <pid>`